# Почему элемент меню остаётся выделенным?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Делаю вход на сайт sitev.ru , при нажатии в меню "Войти", открывается модальное окно входа на сайт. При закрытии окна пункт меню почему то выделен...

Как убрать этот глючок?

Comment: не могли бы вы показать jquery данной функции?

Comment: А точнее добавить [минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) кода в сам вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Вот как решается этот вопрос с помощью CSS:

```
outline: none;
```